# limit using epsilon

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I was wondering if someone could help me with the next steps of this problem. Here is what i have so far but now im stuck on how to further simplify in order to get an N value. [image of work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYsO5.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: factor out 4 on the bottom and you get that $| <expression> | < | \frac{1}{n} | < 4\epsilon \rightarrow n > \frac{1}{4\epsilon}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \frac{10-3n}{8n^2+4n} \right|\leqslant\frac{13n}{8n^2}=\frac{13}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

p.s. find time, please, type your question/attempt in mathjax.